Understanding the logic of "unique existence" proofs
I am learning the lean/mathlib system for automatically checking proofs, and was genuinely surprised that to prove unique existence, the structure there forces us to separately prove these properties:

uniqueness
existence

Surely, uniqueness already implies existence?

Example
Consider the condition $x-2=3.$
First, I simply try $x=5$ without worrying about how I found this "witness". Since $x=5 \implies x-2=5-2=3,$ I have shown that the condition is satisfied by this solution. I can see that this shows the existence of a solution, but doesn't show there are no more.
Next, I apply a series of algebraic manipulations on the given condition, and I may arrive at a set of solutions. I arrive at a single solution: $x-2=3 \implies x-2+2=3+2 \implies x=5.$ If the condition were a quadratic, then the algebraic manipulations would lead me to two solutions.
Hence, I have shown that the condition leads to a unique solution (which automatically proves existence), and I didn't need to separately show existence and uniqueness.

For this example, am I correct that proving existence is redundant?
If so, then is this just for such simple cases?


See also: Unique candidate that fails on Math Educators SE

@ryang Why did you replace a clear title with a vague one?

@user3840170 The original title, which does accurately (and neutrally) reflect the OP's query, shouldn't be changed to a loaded, leading question.

I'm very surprised at all the sentiments here saying that people perceive that mathematics has a different definition of "unique" from standard English. I've never perceived that. I think there's a simpler alternative explanation that allows us all to remain speaking the same language: that is, when someone says "proof of uniqueness:" followed by a proof of ≤1 instance, they are merely abbreviating; if they were to spell it out more explicitly, what they really mean by "proof of uniqueness" is "proof of uniqueness assuming existence (where we have just shown, or are about to show, existence)".

... Also, typically (but not always) the existence half of the proof is presented first, so that existence is established before uniqueness is even mentioned.  When done in this order, it's clear that subsequent use of the word "uniqueness" is meaningful as we all understand it.  In general I'm not a fan of proofs that do it in the opposite order and just call it "proof of uniqueness" without having established existence first, since that seems like sloppy language and is an unnecessary speedbump for readers who may not have seen a lot of existence-and-uniquenss proofs.

@ryang The edited title, unlike the original vague clickbait, reflects the actual problem the asker came with, as expressed by the question body. Titles are not required to be “neutral”, whatever that is supposed to mean.

@user3840170 I'm with ryang-- it's nuanced, but the original title is the accurate and neutral feeling one (not clickbait), to me, and should not be changed to something that, in my perception, has a different, specifically more-opinionated tone.  I'd be uncomfortable to have it changed to that, if I were the OP.

Nonsense. Once you submit a question to our site, it is ours to edit as we please. Being “neutral“ or “opinionated“ is a meaningless concern too. The only thing that matters is for the title to reflect the problem asked about as precisely as can reasonably fit. And “Understanding the logic” could refer to literally anything; while browsing questions by titles (like when searching for duplicates), one wouldn’t know what specific difficulty the asker is facing without clicking through to read the body as well, and that’s what makes the title clickbait.

Uniqueness implies existence in everyday parlance, but not in mathematics.
This is awkward to speak about in ordinary natural language, because any obvious phrasing of the uniqueness property already implicitly presumes existence.  For example, if someone says that for a given constant $a$, $ax + 1 = 0$ “has a unique real solution”, removing the word “unique” gives you a statement of existence of a solution.  Even just the definite article “the” carries an implicit assumption of existence.  This is related to how we often tend to have trouble accepting vacuous statements as true: Gricean maxims are essentially one big licence to assume “you probably wouldn’t tell me this if it were useless” (while talking about non-existent things is presumed useless), so an ordinary-language claim like “all unicorns are blue” is usually taken to imply unicorns exist, and “the solution is unique” is taken to imply a solution exists.
But in formal logic, you can actually talk about uniqueness without having it imply existence.  That is to say, you can establish that any two elements of the set are equal without proving the set contains any elements at all – and in fact it may very well be actually empty.
Consider this definition: a function $f : X \to Y$ is weakly constant if and only if
$$ \forall a \in X : \forall b \in X : f(a) = f(b) $$
This is a statement of uniqueness of the… umm… err… uniqueness of any potential value in the range of $f$.  But it will be also (vacuously) true if the range of $f$ is empty, which happens when $X$ is empty, and therefore $f$ is an empty function.  (You think it’s wrong?  Then show us the $a$ and $b$ for which $f(a) \ne f(b)$.)  A definition of a constant function implying uniqueness and existence would be
$$ \exists a \in X : \forall b \in X : f(a) = f(b) $$
under which an empty function is not considered constant.

This reply has been incredibly helpful - thank you.

It may be a fool's errand to try to formally parse the idiomatic speech of natural language, but even in FOL, depending on which equivalent definition you use, you may start with an existential quantifier. (See my answer.) Only when you use the equivalent conjunction can we easily tease out the "at most one" component (uniqueness) from the "at least one" component (existence).

Another example
Consider the even numbers, $2\mathbb Z:=\{\ldots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\ldots\}.$ I can easily prove that if there exists a multiplicative unit in this set, then it is unique:

Let $1'$ and $1''$ be multiplicative units in $2\mathbb Z,$ i.e. for all $x\in\mathbb Z$ we have $1'\cdot x=x\cdot 1'=x$ and $1''\cdot x=x\cdot 1''=x.$ Then $1'=1'\cdot 1''=1'',$ i.e. a multiplicative unit is unique.

But I haven't here proved that there is such an element in $2\mathbb Z.$ Indeed, there is actually no such element in $2\mathbb Z.$

This is the key difference. One common way of proving uniqueness is to prove the following statement: 'assume x and y are objects with the required properties, then x=y'. This does not prove existence.

this is an excellent example, accessible to beginners like me, thank you

@Penelope. Thank you. I'm glad that I decided to post this example, although there were already several answers.

I think 'uniqueness' is a bit ambiguous. Some will say that uniqueness means 'exactly one', whereas others will say it means 'at most one'.  In math, we typically mean the latter, but I think our intuition would go with the former. But yeah, if it's the latter, then you'll still need to prove existence, since 'at most one' is consistent with there being no solutions at all.

Bram, do people really typically consider $x^2=-1$ to have a unique real solution? Or is "unique := at most one" a misunderstanding arising from uniqueness proofs sometimes being mislabelled as (I) existence; (II) uniqueness (instead of (I) existence; (II) existence⇒ uniqueness ) due to "there exists a unique solution" being synonymous with "there is a unique solution"?

Bram - thanks, your comment that the language is ambiguous is comforting. The reformulation as (1) at most one, and (2) at least one - as suggested by copper.hat is very helpful. A further discussion also suggests (1) unique, if exists, and (2) exists - which makes sense to me but I'm not expert enough sat this is absolutely correct.
Furthermore, I'd like to ask whether using reversible steps from a hypothesis to a solution means the solution really exists and in the number suggested by the reversible algebra/logic steps?

@ryang - I was going to suggest (I) unique if exists, (II) exists.

@ryang Yes, people can say that $ x^2=-1$ has a unique real solution. Sometimes people forget that the thing must exist. I have encountered several papers under such situation. When it is wanted more precision, people would avoid saying it. However, not always one wants precision.

@ryang To me indeed saying that $x^2 = -1$ has a unique real solution sounds like an extreme use of language, but the phrase "uniqueness of solutions" is completely equivalent to "existence of at most one solution". The phrase itself contains no "has a" part, so it doesn't imply existence.

@ryang This would not be the first case where an intentionally simple example doesn't line up with what has to be done in more complex cases.  In more complex proofs, it may be possible to prove $\le1$ (uniqueness as 'at most one') while being unable to prove $\gt 1$ (existence).  When using existence and uniqueness to prove some next step, often you only need one of the properties.  Making uniqueness mean 'exactly one' would mean it is a property that is harder to use in such cases.

@CortAmmon What's in a name? Your complex proof remains essentially the same whether its subproof of $y≤1$ is labelled 'proof of uniqueness' or labelled 'conditional proof of uniqueness' or simply labelled 'proof that $y≤1$'. $\quad$ (In this Answer, I've elaborated on what I think are the roots of the impression/misconception that 'uniquely' means 'at most one'—rather than 'exactly one'—but we can agree to disagree on which of the three labels is inaccurate!)

@Adayah Your argument is just specious: of course phrase A can imply concept B without explicitly containing the words for concept B, and besides it doesn't even make sense to expect the phrases "has a" and "uniqueness of solutions" to grammatically/syntactically cohere. $\quad$ Whether 'unique' means exactly one or at most one is a matter of definition, not logic.

@ryang The argument is not specious, perhaps you just didn't understand it. Regarding your points: 1. I never said A can not imply B without explicitly mentioning it, I only said that in this case - in my opinion - it doesn't. 2. What makes you think I expect the phrases to grammatically/syntactically cohere? 3. It is obvious that the discussion rests on the grounds of definitions, not logic. I described how I interpret these phrases and noticed that the interpretation is not unnatural, since "uniqueness" doesn't linguistically imply "existence" (neither logically, but that's irrelevant).

Maybe I should have inserted a second "to me" disclaimer in that comment to more strongly indicate that I was only sharing my view, but even now this looks like an unnecessary repetition.


to prove unique existence, the structure there forces us to separately prove these properties:

uniqueness
existence


More accurately, the conjunction of the properties

at most one; i.e., not more than one (conditional uniqueness)
at least one; i.e., existence

is equivalent to the property

exactly one, i.e., uniqueness ("unique existence" basically means this).


Surely, uniqueness already implies existence?

Yes.

Example
Consider the condition $x-2=3.$


I arrive at a
single solution: $x-2=3 \implies x-2+2=3+2 \implies x=5.$

Here, you've proven that there is at most one solution (Property 1: there is a unique solution, if it exists). Note that this step by itself shows only that $x=5$ is a candidate solution, which may turn out to be extraneous, in which case the given condition actually has no solution.
Note also that in this part, uniqueness has not actually been proven.

Since $x=5 \implies x-2=5-2=3,$ I have shown that the
condition is satisfied by this solution. I can see that this shows the
existence of a solution

Here, you've proven that there is at least one solution (Property 2: there exists a solution).

So, I have shown that the condition leads to a unique solution
(which automatically proves existence), and I didn't need to separately
show existence and uniqueness.

More simply: your previous two steps together entails the required conclusion: that there is exactly one solution (there is a unique solution).


For this example, am I correct that proving existence is redundant?


Your proof of uniqueness already contains a proof of existence.


If so, then is this just for such simple cases?


No.

If the
condition were a quadratic, then the algebraic manipulations would
lead me to two solutions.

Manipulating a quadratic equation needn’t give rise to two (real) solutions: the manipulation
$$x^2+2=0\implies (x^2+2)(x^3-4x)=0\implies x=-2,0,2$$ has created 3 solutions (all extraneous).

Addendum
I disagree that between "exactly one" and "at most one", the word "unique" means the latter (and I cannot find any source to substantiate this claim). After all, $∃_{=1}$ is called the uniqueness quantifier, and every element of a function's domain is said to have a unique mapping.
Further counteracting any unequivocal claim that in mathematical writing the word "unique" doesn't mean "exactly one":
1,
2,
3,
4.

Thanks, this is helpful.. Does the use of reversible steps to progress from the given hypothesis/conditions to a candidate solution, then ensure that solution is not "extraneous"? In which case we can say, using bidirectional implications, $x-2=3 \iff x-2+2=3+2 \iff x=5$?

Also - a reformulation of the proof requirements for me could be : (1) show "unique, if exists", (2) show "exists". Is this wording valid? The addition of "if exist" for me makes the motivation much clearer, and cuts through different interpretations of "unique"

@Penelope 1. (1) show unique, if exists, (2) show exists $\quad$ Yes, exactly. $\qquad$ 2. Does the use of reversible steps.... $\quad$ Yes: reversibility and extraneous solutions. Generally, the forward direction gives candidate solutions (no other solution can exist), while the reverse direction gives definite solutions (these solutions definitely exist). But don't actually combine the two proof parts into the "reversible steps" format, which is more prone to carelessness.

Don Hatch left a comment that I agree with: my initial response blurred the distinction between:

There exists at most one solution.

There exists a unique solution.


I regard this as a mistake on my part.  I have edited my answer to correct this mistake.

Consider the statement:
$$x - 2 = 3 \implies x = 5. \tag1 $$
(1) above, which is a true statement, merely asserts that if a solution exists then it must be unique.  However, (1) above does not assert that any solution exists.
Worded differently, (1) above asserts that there is at most one solution, but does not assert that there is at least one solution.
More explicitly, (1) above asserts that if there exists a value $~x = x_0~$ that satisfies the equation $~x-2 = 3,~$ then the only possible value for $~x_0~$ is the value $~x_0 = 5.~$
Now consider the statement:
$$x = 5 \implies x - 2 = 3. \tag2 $$
(2) above, which is also a true statement, merely asserts that there exists at least one solution.  However, (2) above does not assert that there is at most one solution.
More explicitly, (2) above asserts that if $~x_0 = 5,~$ then $~x = x_0~$ is a satisfying value to the equation $~x - 2 = 3.~$
However, (2) above does not exclude the possibility that there might be other satisfying values $~x_0~$ to the equation $~x - 2 = 3,~$ besides the value $~x_0 = 5.$

As other responses have discussed, there is ambiguity around the word uniqueness.
Prior to my editing this answer, I (in effect) indicated that statement (1) above is asserting uniqueness.  My intention however, was that statement (1) is asserting that there is at most one solution.
After thinking about it, my (subjective) view is that asserting that an equation has a unique solution is equivalent to making both of the following assertions.

The equation has at most one solution.

The equation has at least one solution.



Thanks for trying to help. Why does the first part not prove existence? Forgive me for using non-mathematical language, but I can see with my eyes the solution exists, it is $x=5$, the RHS of $x-2=3 \implies x=5$. Am I reading this statement wrong? Is there a scenario where I end up with $x=k$ but the number of solutions is strictly less than one, ie zero not one?

@Penelope Consider the true statement $~(x - 2)^2 < 0 \implies x = 5.~$

A typical example is $\sqrt{x} = -1$. If you square both sides, you get $x=1$, but this is not a solution to the original equation.

@user2661923 Hey, do you really consider $x^2=−1$
to have a unique real solution? [The rest of my comment is under Bram's answer.]

@ryang Mathematicians don't.  Personally, I use the phrase there exists a unique solution to represent that exactly one solution exists.  Then, in other contexts, if I want to say either that at most one solution exists, or at least one solution exists, I will avoid using the word unique.

@Penelope Your prior knowledge of numbers gets in the way a bit here, I think (you already know 5 exists). Suppose your domain is $\mathbb N$, with the appropriate axioms, and that you have x + 5 = 3. There is no natural number that satisfies this, but, you may nevertheless be able to show that if there was one, call it $a$, it must be unique. E.g., assume $a_1$ and $a_2$ are arbitrary representatives of distinct solutions, then show $a_1 = a_2$. But $a \notin \mathbb N$. Now imagine a setting where you don't know a priori what all the objects are, and all you have to go on are the axioms.

There's a subtle point here that may lead to confusion. $S$ is not the solution set, but the candidate solution set. I.e. "if $x$ such and such, then $x$ is in $S$" proves that the solution set is included in $S$. That's the uniqueness proof. Then existence proof would be that both sets are in fact equal, or in the general case, that the solution set is not empty.

@user2661923 Just to be crystal clear:  when you make the (problematic, to me) statement "This proves uniqueness" in your answer, what you mean is, precisely, the less-problematic words that you say a bit later: "what you have proven is that if a solution exists, then it must be unique".  Right?   I'm having trouble reconciling this with what you say in your comment above:  "if I want to say that at most one solution exists, or [...], I will avoid using the word unique", which seems like very good policy to me.

@DonHatch +1 to your comment, which (in effect) asserts that my original answer was careless in its use of the word unique.  I agree that I was careless, and I have edited my answer accordingly.

@user2661923 Re: your EDIT comment: to be clear, it was my comment above that first asked you to clarify that (false) implicit claim in your then Answer! Actually, ConMan’s Answer below did the same thing (signal contradictory positions), and misconception across this page was further reinforced by, presumably, bandwagon effect. With your EDIT, your Answer finally agrees with mine (and md2perp's).

@ryang Absolutely agree, including the bandwagon effect.  The whole episode was not my finest hour.  For some reason, when I read your comment, my conscious mind was satisfied to respond in the comments.  So, communication between my conscious and subconscious mind was blocked.  Then, when I received Don Hatch's comment, the blockade was removed.

Your particular example is special in that linear equations always have (existence) a single (unique) answer. But of course, things can be more complicated:
If $x$ is a real number and it has a multiplicative inverse, that inverse is unique.
Suppose that $y$ and $z$ are each multiplicative inverses of $x$. Then $$y = y \cdot 1 = y \cdot (xz) = (yx)\cdot z = 1 \cdot z = z,$$ so that $$y = z,$$ with the proviso that we already know that $1$ is the multiplicative identity and that multiplication of real numbers is associative.
But of course, not every real number has a multiplicative inverse.
Many times, an existence proof has non-reversible steps (or at least, steps that are not reversible in a unique way).  How do you differentiate between your steps showing that $x-2=3$ has a unique solution and that $x^2 = 9$ does not? Ok, we all know that taking square roots introduces a complication (i.e. they are not precisely reversible), but in general, many problems are solved by nonreversible processes. Showing that $x^2 = 9$ has a solution only requires me to exhibit $x = 3$. But of course, we know that solution is not unique.
As a more "regular" algebraic situation, consider the two system of equations $$\begin{align*}
x + y &= 5\\
x-y &= 3\\
\end{align*}$$ which has only the solution $x = 4, y = 1$.
However, the system $$\begin{align*}
x + y &= 5\\
2x+2y &= 10\\
\end{align*}$$ also has $x = 4, y = 1$ as a solution, along with infinitely many others.  The person who solves the first system might choose a solution path that happens to prove existence and uniqueness at the same time. However, I can solve the first system by simply exhibiting $(4,1)$ as a solution and then claiming that since the lines defined by the system have distinct slopes, they must intersect in only one point.  That is as valid of a proof of existence and uniqueness as going through the more typical algebra to deduce $(4,1)$ is the only solution.


Surely, uniqueness already implies existence?

No. Uniqueness and existence are independent of one another.
Existence and uniqueness are often stated in the form:
$~~~~~~\exists a: [P(a) \land \forall b:[P(b)\implies a=b]] $
Equivalently and more useful in this context, it can be restated as the conjunction:
$~~~~~~\forall a,b: [P(a) \land P(b) => a=b]~~\land ~~ \exists a: P(a) $
The leftmost term (uniqueness) means there exists at most one $x$ such that $P(x)$.
The rightmost term (existence) means there exists at least one $x$ such that  $P(x)$.
Each term is independent of the other, e.g. it is possible that there exist at most one $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true (uniqueness holds), and there exists no $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true (existence does not hold).


Surely, uniqueness already implies existence?

In the context of binary relations on a set, you can have uniqueness without existence. Consider the following for example:
$~~~~~~X=\{0,1,2\}$
$~~~~~~f=\{(1,0), (2,1)\} \subset X^2$
By inspection, we have uniqueness:
$~~~~~~\forall a,b,c \in X:[(a,b)\in f~ \land ~(a,c)\in f \implies b=c]$
We do not, however, have existence:
$~~~~~~\neg \forall a\in X: \exists b\in X: (a,b) \in f$
$~~~~~~a=0~$ being the counter-example

Whether uniqueness implies existence simply depends on whether you're defining it to mean exactly one or at most one.

@ryang See Addendum

I'm just pointing out that your Answer is premised on defining 'unique' as 'at most one', and can be condensed to just its first sentence.

@ryang In the addendum, using the alternative, equivalent definition, I am effectively defining 'unique' as 'at most one' AND 'at least one.'

Deleted Addendum. Submitted it as an alternative answer.

The idea that uniqueness doesn't imply existence makes a little more sense when we have a family of equations where some have solutions and some don't, and we want to say that for the ones that do have a solution it is unique. This is often important in systems of differential equations as well as in linear algebra, but as a simple example we can say that the solutions to $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}} = A$ are unique, since the left-hand side is an injective function.
It is true that the more exact language would be to say that solutions are unique where they exist, but when it comes to the proofs themselves a typical uniqueness proof starts by assuming the existence of a solution, and then showing that there cannot be a second distinct solution, which means we wind up proving $\textrm{solution exists} \implies \textrm{solution is unique}$. As a result, the proof is still true in the case where there are no solutions, because $F \implies T$ is taken to be true.

Your Answer starts by suggesting that something can be unique without existing ("The idea that uniqueness doesn't imply existence makes a little more sense when..."), in other words, that 'unique' means at most one, but the entire rest of your answer contradicts this by patently using 'unique' to mean exactly one. $\quad$ (Actually, user2661923's Answer above also starts by implying that 'unique' means at most one, contradicting their comment under the Answer clarifying that 'unique' means exactly one.)

@ryang It's part of the trickiness of the language. At best, I could suggest it's a difference between the property of being unique (which at least in English does imply existence) versus the nature of a uniqueness proof (which only proves the conditional uniqueness assuming existence).


I'm just pointing out that your opening sentence contradicts the rest of your Answer. $\quad$ 2. Regarding your comment: it isn't complicated/tricky: the proof of "the conditional uniqueness assuming existence" is merely one part of the uniqueness proof, just as the proof of pigs fly ⇒ God exists simply isn't the proof of God exists.


I disagree that the conditional is only one part of the proof. Proving that a solution, where it exists, is unique, is a valid uniqueness proof (at least to me).

(I) You said that in English, 'unique' means 'n=1', and your entire answer (save for its first sentence) supports this; (II) you agree that the proof of 'n=1' has two parts: 'n≥=1⇒n=1' (n≤1) and 'existence' (n≥1). Therefore, you'd uncontroversially agree the proof that 'a solution, where it exists, is unique' is merely part of the proof the uniqueness proof. $\quad$ Assuming  that I haven't misunderstood you, let's agree to disagree.

I'm saying that whether normal English would suggest unique means exactly one, there are plenty of English words that mean something different when used in mathematics, and I'm fine with unique being one of them.

"There are plenty of English words that mean something different when used in mathematics." $\quad$ Oh, I totally concur; as a matter of fact, the most common meaning of 'unique' is neither n=1 nor n≤1, but that there isn't a duplicate, which doesn't actually preclude n>1 ("I own a unique stone" is compatible with me owning 4 common stones and 1 special stone).

@ryang It's mine :-)  I really am stumbling over that first sentence "The idea that uniqueness doesn't imply existence makes a little more sense when...".  The whole rest of the answer makes perfect sense to me, and in fact I think it's really insightful and helpful for giving clarity about what's going on here, and about how the sloppy phrasing may have come about.    But "uniqueness doesn't imply existence" still isn't clicking... I don't think there's any need to make or defend that claim, and when speaking carefully, we simply don't say that. I wonder if that part could just be rephrased?

Problem: What is the largest real number?
Let $z$ denote the largest real number, that is, $z\geq x$ for all real $x$. Clearly, $z$ is unique: If there is another $\hat{z}$ which would be the largest real number, we have $x\leq z$ and $x\leq\hat{z}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $z\leq\hat{z}$ and $\hat{z}\leq z$. and Hence, $z=\hat{z}$.
Hence, we have shown uniqueness, but not existence.

Your example may be a bit confusing because it is so simple, since by very few manipulations you arrive at $x=5$, which obviously exists and is unique.
I should also note that in many cases (e.g., solutions of diferential equations), uniqueness is actually much easier to show that existence. So it is not uncommon for math courses to prove uniqueness first.

@DonHatch Well, yes, that's kind of the point, isn't it? (The formulation may be a bit tongue-in-cheek, but still.)

@DonHatch Well, we have shown uniqueness: if therere are two $z$ satisfying the condition, they are equal. This is the point in the context of the question: uniqueness is different from existence, because you can prove one without the other. The formulation is a bit sloppy because clearly there is no such $z$, but that doesn't affect the main part.

@DonHatch If you read my comment, it clearly says"...uniqueness: if therere are two z satisfying the condition, they are equal.". This seems to be the root of your (and the OP's) confusion. Understood thsi way, uniqueness is clearly different from existence, and it can be proven independently. And the fact that words can mean somwehat different things in everyday languange and in mathematical (or any field-specific terms) should not be a surprise, I'd say.

I don't think I've done a good job of making the point I was trying to make.  Rather than continuing to repeat myself, I'm going to delete all my comments above, and then this one.  Apologies for the noise.
